# If url is root domain, add class to id

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to get the user `url` on my site. I want to show if the user url is the **root domain**, add `active` `class` to the `id` `home-item-menu`. If not, don't do nothing.

I was using `window.location.href` and `window.location.host` but didn't work.

For the rest of section's I was using `indexof` (and the string that the url has), but because the root domain don't have any string I don't know how to do it.

```
  <nav class="cl-effect-5">
            <li class="nav-item" id="home-item-menu">
                <a class="nav-link menu-rucab js-scroll-trigger" href="#home"><span data-hover="HOME">HOME</span></a>
            </li>
                    </nav>
                  <nav class="cl-effect-5">
            <li class="nav-item" id="rucab-item-menu">
                <a class="nav-link menu-rucab js-scroll-trigger" href="#rucab"><span data-hover="RUCAB">RUCAB</span></a>
            </li>
             </nav>
                    <nav class="cl-effect-5">
            <li class="nav-item" id="inscripciones-item-menu">
                <a class="nav-link menu-rucab js-scroll-trigger" href="#inscripciones"><span data-hover="INSCRIPCIONES">INSCRIPCIONES</span></a>
            </li>
             </nav>
             <nav class="cl-effect-5">
            <li class="nav-item" id="habitaciones-item-menu">
                <a class="nav-link menu-rucab js-scroll-trigger" href="#habitaciones"><span data-hover="HABITACIONES">HABITACIONES</span></a>
            </li>
             </nav>
              <nav class="cl-effect-5">
            <li class="nav-item" id="staff-item-menu">
                <a class="nav-link menu-rucab js-scroll-trigger" href="#staff"><span data-hover="STAFF">STAFF</span></a>
            </li>
             </nav>
             <nav class="cl-effect-5">
            <li class="nav-item" id="blog-item-menu">
                <a class="nav-link menu-rucab js-scroll-trigger" href="#contact"><span data-hover="BLOG">BLOG</span></a>
            </li>
             </nav>
                    <nav class="cl-effect-5">
            <li class="nav-item" id="contacto-item-menu">
                <a class="nav-link menu-rucab js-scroll-trigger" href="#contacto"><span data-hover="CONTACTO">CONTACTO</span></a>
            </li>
             </nav>
```

JQuery/Javascript

```
$( document ).ready(
    function() {
var url = window.location.href;
var host = window.location.host;
if(url.indexOf('http://' + host + '/') != -1) {
    document.getElementById("home-item-menu").classList.add("active");
}
if (document.URL.indexOf("habitaciones") > -1)
{
    document.getElementById("habitaciones-item-menu").classList.add("active");

} else if (document.URL.indexOf("contacto") > -1) {
    document.getElementById("contacto-item-menu").classList.add("active");

} else if (document.URL.indexOf("rucab") > -1) {
    document.getElementById("rucab-item-menu").classList.add("active");

} else if (document.URL.indexOf("inscripciones") > -1) {
    document.getElementById("inscripciones-item-menu").classList.add("active");

} else if (document.URL.indexOf("staff") > -1) {
    document.getElementById("staff-item-menu").classList.add("active");

} else if (document.URL.indexOf("blog") > -1) {
    document.getElementById("blog-item-menu").classList.add("active");

}
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the condition `window.location.pathname === '/'`:

```
if(window.location.pathname === '/') {
    document.getElementById("home-item-menu").classList.add("active");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Pedro Corchero Murga you can use javascript sessions to achieve this set the text of the nav item to javascript session and get that session on load function and check the conditions if you don't familiar with javascript sessions you can see this link : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_sessionstorage.asp

Answer (score 0):

First of all, define how you want to tell your application if **this is my root URL**, which one way to achieve this is as follows;

```
function isAtRoot () {
    // Let's say you're currently at 'https://myhome.domain/',
    // and this is your root.
    var href = window.location.href,
        urlWithoutQueryString = href.split('?')[0],
        host = window.location.host,
        regexp = new RegExp("^https?://" + host + "/?$", "i");

    return !!urlWithoutQueryString.match(regexp);
}
```

Or you can also use [window.location.pathname](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/pathname) for this.

Then, run your javascript like above as follows,

```
if (isAtRoot()) {
    document.getElementById("home-item-menu").classList.add("active");
}
```

However, I'd suggest that you have a list of paths for your site and give it an alias or name to it. Then, run something like `isAtRoot` against it instead, which will have more trust-able precision for future references.

Comment: Nice reply!! How I give it an alias to my list of paths? Which string I need to use. Thanks.

Comment: Well, one way to put it, you can use an object for a key-value pair of your paths, where you can use the `key` as to specify the alias to avoid duplicates.

Comment: I'm a newbie with that sorry, I don't understand nothing, can u put my the exact line that I need to insert? Thanks.